# How to use select dropdown to filter table td value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table which its td value is corresponding to the value of the select dropdown. So when the dropdown is being selected, i would like the table to filter its table row according to the selected value. eg If One is selected,
the table will conduct filter and only show two table row which its td value is 1. Currently,the code isn't working for some reason.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 
  $('#select').change(function() {
   
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#select').find('tr');
  
    dataset.show();
    
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select'>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
</select>

<table border="2">


<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Is data table not compatible with your system? If not then try using that. That will provide you with plenty of options.

Comment: Use `$('table').find('tr')` in place of `$('#select').find('tr')` in above code

Comment: You can customize and use [jQuery Data Table](https://datatables.net/) for your requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use table instead of select

`var dataset = $('table').find('tr');`

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 
  $('#select').change(function() {
   
    var selection = $(this).val();
     var dataset = $('table').find('tr');
  
    dataset.show();
    
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select'>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
</select>

<table border="2">


<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
selectfilter($('table'),$('#select').val());

$('#select').change(function() {       
    var selection = $(this).val();  
    $('table').find('tr').show();        
    selectfilter($('table'),selection);
  });
  
function selectfilter(table ,selection)
{
  table.find('tr').filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select'>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
</select>

<table border="2">


<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>

</table>
```